# keyboard/mouse not responding 16.04LTS after some time

Tags: 16.04, nvidia

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with latest updates (08/May/2017). 
Dell workstation 7810 with nvidia quadro k420. Keyboard is ps2 port attached. Mouse is USB attached in a usb3 slot. Display is (3840x2160) display-port attached. Using the default desktop that comes with 16.04.

Symptom is: My keyboard / mouse /music-playback stops responding after "some time", often when I am not using the system. I've disabled inactivity-lock on the display (no timeout).
The mouse pointer moves OK, but clicking on any icon either on desktop or launchpad, with either mouse-button, does not give a reaction and keyboard does not react.

To recover I switch-off, reboot, and the system behaves normally until at some point it freezes again.

Mostly Firefox is opened, streaming music, or youtube showing a vid , music/video-playback will also stop when the freeze happens abruptly.

I think the hardware is OK because when I boot to Windows-10 it seems not to hang.

This is a new installation (not an upgrade). The most recent change is switch from 1680x1050 to different monitor with 3840x2160). Not sure if that is the cause, but I will eliminate it.

I don't yet have this workstation configured for ssh to see if I can ssh to it, but when in the frozen state occasionally I see the disk light flashing suggesting that Linux is running OK and only the desktop mouse-keyboard are not responding.

Suggestions for troubleshooting this? I am new to Ubuntu but familiar with Linux. I will try a different mouse also.

Comment: I swapped back to the previous monitor without changing software and this resolved the issue. I then installed the nvidia driver as suggested, and swapped in the new monitor and it cured the symptom. I would prefer the nonproprietary driver but need that issue fixed before I can switch back to it.